# 2174 error on upload image base64 in php

Tags: php, mysql

hi use the following code as below

```
if($data['photo']!='')
{
    define("UPLOAD_DIR", "admin/alumni_image/");
    $photo = $data['photo'];// THIS IS YOUR BASE64 ENCODED STRING
    $photo = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $photo);
    $photo = str_replace(' ', '+', $photo);
    $data = base64_decode($photo);
    $time =microtime(true);
    $micro_time=sprintf("%06d",($time - floor($time)) * 1000000);
    $date=new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro_time,$time) );
    $currentDatetime=$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"); 
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . md5($currentDatetime) . '.png';
    $array=explode("/",$file);
    $photoName=$array[2];
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    echo $success;
    $query_photo = "update alumni set photo = '".$photoName."' where alumni_id = '".$insert_id."'";
    $query_run=  mysql_query($query_photo);
}
```

but I got error 2174. I increase the  size of php configuration file like

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

Comment: What is error 2174 and which line gives it?

Comment: when i print $success it return 2174

Comment: file_put_contents returns the number of bytes written. Try to save a bigger/smaller file, and u see that the number changes. This is not a error.

Comment: ok if($success){echo "success"} i could not find any result

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `file_put_contents` [is not an error code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

> This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or **FALSE** on failure.

Thus there appears to be nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: ya it return admin/alumni_image/97e984cec22abde1b1bee12f7ede8363.png

Comment: ya this code work properly on hosting server now i check the php version as php5, date format not supported so i change date format according to php5 thanks  @ Niels Keurentjes